# error in c# when use the loop

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, datatable

I have this error c#

> **foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `int` because `int` does not contain a public definition for `GetEnumerator`.**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ord.GET_ORDER_DETAILS(textBox1.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach(var r in dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(r.Cells[0].Value, r.Cells[1]);            
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You're iterating the row **count** , not Rows... It's like declaring `foreach (var r in 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to add each of rows, just:

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

If you only want 2 columns then try

```
var dtResult = ord.GET_ORDER_DETAILS(textBox1.Text);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtResult;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
foreach (DataRow item in dtResult.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item["Column1"], item["Column2"]);
}
```

Comment: I just want 2 columns

Comment: Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Oh then your method `ord.GET_ORDER_DETAILS(textBox1.Text);` return a datatable?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Ok, for data row you must use `foreach (DataRow item in dtResult.Rows)`, not `foreach (var item in dtResult.Rows)`, i edited ....

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You want to iterate the *rows*, not the *count* of the number of rows.

```
foreach(var r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(r.Cells[0].Value, r.Cells[1]);
}
```

Comment: Try just using `dt.Rows.Add(r[0], r[1])`. What are the errors you're receiving, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Count and try

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ord.GET_ORDER_DETAILS(textBox1.Text);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach(var r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(r.Cells[0].Value, r.Cells[1]);
    }
}
```